# Считывание данных, кодировка

Tags: c#, кодировка, системы-счисления

Есть GPS блок, установленный на транспорте, есть сервер, который получает от него данные в виде 16-ричного числа. В документации к блоку написано
`First when module connects to server, module sends its IMEI. IMEI is sent the same way as encoding barcode. First comes short identifying number of bytes written and then goes IMEI as text (bytes).
For example IMEI 123456789012345 would be sent as 000F313233343536373839303132333435`
Я получаю данные в таком виде как на примере :`000F313233343536373839303132333435`, вопрос, как мне из этого `000F313233343536373839303132333435` получить это `123456789012345`?
ПО принимающее данные пишу на C#.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt64(value, 16)`  возможно поможет конвертирование из hexadecimal into decimal https://stackoverflow.com/q/74148/2360072

Answer (score 0):

У вас, очевидно, передаются байты, соответствующие ASCII-коду. Поэтому вам нужно что-то такое (пишу псевдокод, т. к. не знаю, каким образом вам доставляются данные):

```
short length = ReadShort(); // или BitConverter.ToInt16(ReadBytes(2), 0)
string imei = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ReadBytes(length));
```

Если нужно получить число, то используйте `int.Parse`.